# JavaScript optimizations

Tags: javascript, optimization, spidermonkey

So I've been writing a game in JavaScript (not a web game, using a game engine where JavaScript just happens to be the scripting language). Unfortunately, the game engine's JavaScript engine is an ancient version of SpiderMonkey, which runs my game a bit slowly. While it's not terribly slow, it's slow enough that I decided to do a bit of optimization.

I know some basic optimizations like using local variables instead of globals (which is a good idea anyway), using prefix instead of postfix increment/decrement, counting down instead of up in loops, but what are some more good JavaScript optimizations?

Comment: Profile, profile, profile, profile, and profile your code before you start messing up *anything* with micro-optimizations like loop counter direction.

Comment: Since JS engines are all the rage these days, chances are that your performance problems would be solved if you used a more recent engine in your game. Is that really out of the question?

Comment: Sadly, yes, using a newer JS engine is out of the question. It's complicated, but suffice it to say, I suck at C++, which is what the engine is written in, and the SpiderMonkey version is so old that there have been API changes between it and the newer versions, which means I can't just replace the DLL and would instead have to edit the source.

Comment: Can't up vote Pointy enough. Don't optimize until you know where the slowdowns are, you can cause yourself a lot of trouble that way (in other words, **premature optimization is the root of all evil**). That said, this book has some good info: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596802806

Comment: I do know where the slow downs are, at least sort of. I know what parts of the system need to be optimized. Thanks for the book link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your code is structured, but let's say that parts of it reside in functions or loops, which are run through frequently:

- replace `if()` with `? :` where possible

e.g.

```
if (expr) a = 1;
else a = 2;
```

becomes

```
a = expr ? 1 : 2;
```

- turn a series of `if()`s into a `switch()` if possible
- if you use `substr()`, `substring()` or `slice()` check which one is faster (on an embedded browser I 
  once noticed a difference of factor 3). Keep an eye on their parameters, though!
- avoid recalculation of values or calling the same function with the same parameters again, even if it's just a minor one
- if you access the same element of an array over and over again, store it in a local variable
- `eval()` is very slow (besides the fact that it is evil)
- keep in mind that a JavaScript-engine is single-threaded. Nothing runs parallel, not even timers or intervals.

If the code turns out to be hard to read, write comments.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of messing up the source code did you give a try to the [Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/closure/compiler/) ? It's a compiler from javascript to javascript that does a few optimizations. Mostly are for size but the resulting js also runs often faster. No idea if optimizations are however V8-specific.